# Set bearer token in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, bearer-token

I have a web backend using NodeJS. I want to retrieve data from another server using a link eg `https://evoDMSTDev/api/api_event_all.php`, and must use a bearer token eg `71D55F6907509` to access it. So, where I have to set the token so I can retrieve that data and display it on my web backend?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are using? Is it Node.js or PHP? Are you trying to make API/AJAX call from client side or server to server API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create like this in node js, and then just call the `obj` in your `.ejs`

```
request({
    uri : 'https://evoDMSTDev/api/api_events_all.php',
    auth: {
        'bearer': '71D55F99570209'
    },
    rejectUnauthorized: false,//add when working with https sites
    requestCert: false,//add when working with https sites
    agent: false,//add when working with https sites
}, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
         console.log(error);
      } else {
         obj = JSON.parse(body);
      }
}
```